# Proving that the relation $a \le b \iff b - a \ge 0$ is antisymmetric and total.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Over $\mathbb{R}$ is defined a relation $\le$ in the following way:
>
> $$\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} [a \le b \iff b - a \ge 0]$$
>
> Demonstrate that $\le$ is a relation of total order.

For a relation to be of total order, it has to be reflexive, transitive, antisymmetric and total.

I already proved reflexive and transitive, but not so with the other two:

---

**Antisymmetric**

We have to prove that for arbitrary elements $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$(a \le b \land b \le a) \implies a = b$$

We start:

$$a \le b \land b \le a$$

$$b - a \ge 0 \land a - b \ge 0$$

$$b - a + a - b \ge 0$$

$$0 \ge 0$$

**Umm... True. That's true. But I doubt this proves that $a = b$.**

---

**Total**

We have to prove that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, $(a \le b \lor b \le a)$:

$$a \le b \lor b \le a$$

$$b - a \ge 0 \lor a - b \ge 0$$

$$b - a + a - b \ge 0$$

$$0 \ge 0$$

**Ok, clearly I don't see the bigger picture here.**

---

As you can observe, I have the basic mindset of writing what I want to prove, then evaluate it with my premise and then continuously simplify it.

I fear that I'm missing the point of this kind of demonstration - I'm not particularly interested in this one exercise, but rather understand better the apparently abstract process that tends to be made for this kind of problem. Can you advice me here?

Comment: What do you know about $\geq 0$? For example, have you shown that $\geq$ is a relation of total order?

Comment: How do you define $a\ge0$ for $a$?   The first part might be easier by contradiction.

Comment: I fear that the exercise makes no remarks about $\ge$.

Comment: Your and & or become unexplainably + at some point. I am not a logician but I think it is there that you mess up and loose any sort of information

Comment: @user01123581321345589144...: Sounds likely. It seemed like my only option at the time, though. Since both expressions are $\ge 0$, adding them should still be $\ge 0$. That was probably unnecessary I guess.

Comment: ok, let me try: you have that $b - a \ge 0$ and $-(b-a) = a-b \ge 0$. Assume for the sake of contradiction that $b -a \neq 0 \Longrightarrow b - a > 0$. Then its additive inverse, $-(b - a)$ would be strictly negative, a contradiction since $a - b \ge 0$. Thus $b - a = 0$, hence $a = b$. (I am not 100% sure that logicians would agree with me, but it is a starting point, I think :D )

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have $\ge$ defined (along with its total order), I would proceed as follows (outline/sketch):

**Antisymmetric**
$$(a\le b) \wedge (b\le a)$$
$$(b-a)\ge 0 \wedge (a-b) \ge 0$$
$$(b-a)\ge 0 \wedge -(b-a)\ge 0$$

Now, we know that $x\ge 0 \wedge -x \ge 0 \implies x = 0$ (I'm assuming this can be worked out from whatever definition of $\ge$ you're using).  Thus, we have:
$$b-a = 0$$
$$b=a$$

**Total**

Assuming we know that $\ge$ defines a total order on $\Bbb{R}$ (from class or given in the book), this is straightforward.  We then know that:
$$\forall a, b \in \Bbb{R}, (a \ge b)\vee(b\ge a)$$

Thus, let $a$ and $b$ be arbitrary elements of $\Bbb{R}$.  Then we know that $(a\ge b) \vee (b\ge a)$.  That is, $(a - b \ge 0)\vee (b-a \ge 0)$.  By applying the definition of $\le$, we have $(b \le a) \vee (a \le b)$, as was to be shown.